# Permission Denied Xampp Windows

Tags: php, xampp

I copied the files from server to my local host but I have error "Warning: require_once(C:\xampp\php\pear): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\Foldername\controller\DraftingTimeSheetController.php on line 4

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\Foldername\controller\DraftingTimeSheetController.php on line 4"

This help me I am using windows 10 xampp server

Comment: What happens on line 4 of `DraftingTimeSheetController.php`? Show us your code please.

Comment: require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/model/DraftingTimeSheets.php'));
require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/model/OnSite.php'));

Comment: anyone with a solution?

Comment: It should just be a case of ensuring the account which runs the Apache service has read permission on the relevant php files

Comment: @KletoRalphSalvo Note that you can edit your question to include your code reference (and use the formatting bar option to highlight it as code inline or block text). I'm having a similar permissions issue with XAMPP Windows but I'm not sure yet if it's related. I think however your issue is with Apache not having permission to a folder or file in xampp.

Answer (score -1):

You should give these files read permissions

```
sudo chmod -R 777 "Your file"
```

Comment: I edit all permissions to Full Control but I got the same error

Comment: I am using windows 10 by the way

Comment: @liquidot: sudo and chmod are windows commands?? ... Plus 777 would not be my recommendation, whether a windows system or not.

Comment: This is a strange solution considering your suggestion is not a built-in Windows CLI command. Are you using something special to run this on Windows 10? Like, WLS or Docker or VirtualBox? I'm a little confused on whether your suggestion was meant for Linux or something else.